# How to extract data from a data table in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I am asking a pretty basic question:
how to pull out "Female" data from this table
and calculating average number for "Females" using R.
Two columns 1. sex   2. height

```
sex    height
Male   75.00000
Male   70.00000
Female 65.00000
Female 66.00000
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Being a basic question, there are many answers you could have [researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). What did you try? Aggregation is one of the most basic data analysis steps. Every data science tools has multiple ways of running it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using data.table, use this

```
dt[,avg:=mean(height),by=.(sex)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With `base R` we can extract the second column based on the first column value of 'Female' and apply the `mean` on the `vector`

```
mean(Heights[[2]][Heights[[1]] == 'Female'], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or if we use a group by operation, can get the `mean` of both 'Female', 'Male'

```
aggregate(height ~ sex, Heights, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
#    sex height
#1 Female   65.5
#2   Male   72.5
```

#### data

```
Heights <- structure(list(sex = c("Male", "Male", "Female", "Female"), height = c(75, 
70, 65, 66)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: aggregate(height ~ sex, Heights, mean, na.rm = TRUE) - this formula worked very well, thanks a lot! I dont know why my previous comments disappeared...